# Wolfram says sum diverges, but Mathematica gives a numerical value for infinite sum

Tags: summation, wolfram-alpha-queries

Take this sum for example:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{\log(n!)}$$
Wolfram says that this does not converge by the comparison test. However, when I use Mathematica's `NSum` function, it returns a numerical value for the summation. Who should I trust?

```
NSum[1/Log[n!], {n, 2, \[Infinity]}]=6.12902
```

Comment: Stirling: $\log n!\sim n\log n$, and $\frac{1}{n\log n}$ is not summable.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform by not summable, do you mean divergent?

Comment: yes indeed.${}$

Comment: So what exactly happens when Mathematica gives me a numerical answer?

Comment: About `Regularization`?

Comment: You should have mentioned that Mathematica throws error messages when executing `NSum[1/Log[n!], {n, 2, \[Infinity]}]`...

Comment: From the doc page for `NSum` under the section Possible Issues: "NSum may not detect divergence for some infinite sums" and "Convergence verification is based on a ratio test that is inconclusive when equal to 1", both of which apply here.

Comment: I made test PHP script which evaluates numerically this series. My results are `n=23,166,000,000; sum=6.2010890765879; term_n=1.8878160302708E-12`. So clearly a bigger value than mathematica's `6.12902`, but it's not surprising, because series converges very slowly and mathematica doesn't have a patience :-)

Comment: Nowadays Wolfram prints 5.34229.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When a command has issues, it is a good idea to check the **Possible Issues** section of the doc page for the command, in this case [`NSum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSum.html).  Two of the issues apply to the OP's case:

> `NSum` may not detect divergence for some infinite sums
>
> Convergence verification is based on a ratio test that is inconclusive when equal to 1

[*Edit notice:* I made a mistake in the integral test which I've deleted.]

Answer (score 16):

[image]
As the message shows, NSum works on limited recursions. Mathematica does not consider the "mathematical converge" when it works on NSum. Therefore Mathematica finds that this sum converges too slowly, and threw out the answer after MaxRecursion.