# User plug-in methods for SumConvergence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation, undocumented

[@Валерий Заподовников](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/82985/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) remarks:

> [BTW, it is also quite bad that Mathematica does not have Bertrand test.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224072/why-doesnt-mathematica-provide-an-answer-while-wolframalpha-does-concerning-a/268804#268804)

*Is there a way to extend the convergence tests in `SumConvergence[]` with user-defined methods?*

In the linked Q&A, the series whose convergence is in question is given in the following command, which returns unevaluated:

```
SumConvergence[1 - Cos[Pi/n], n]
```

@Валерий points out that Bertand's test works on this series. Is there a way to apply Bertrand's test or [any other test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvergenceTests.html) on this series?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can pass a function of the form `usermethod[expr, k]` to `Method`, although I cannot find any documentation for it:

```
Sum[expr, k, Method -> usermethod]
```

The specification `usermethod` should be a `Symbol` or a string. A non-string is passed through `ToExpression[ToString[usermethod]]`, so if it is a non-symbol expression, it needs to make the round-trip unaltered. A good way to do this is to use `SetOptions` on `ToString` to set `FormatType -> InputForm`. A string value for `usermethod` is passed directly through `ToExpression` and putting string quotes around a complicated expression for `usermethod` can be an easier way than `SetOptions`. See `multitest`, `lct` and the ***Update*** below for examples.

The return values are handled thus:

| Result | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `True` | Converges |
| `False` | Diverges |
| `$Failed` | Indeterminate; `SumConvergence` unevaluated |
| unevaluated | Indeterminate; `SumConvergence` unevaluated |
| Garbage | Garbage |

An example of garbage:

```
foo[expr_, k_] := Umm ...;
SumConvergence[1 - Cos[Pi/n], n, Method -> foo]
(*  Umm ...  *)
```

It is as though the test is treated as successful and the user-defined return value is assumed to have some meaning for the user.

Example: *Bertrand's test*

```
bertrand[expr_, k_] := Module[{ratio, res},
   ratio = Together[(expr /. k -> k + 1)/expr];
   res = Limit[Log[k] (k (1/ratio - 1) - 1), k -> Infinity];
   res > 1 /; FreeQ[res, Limit | Indeterminate] && res != 1
   ];

SumConvergence[1 - Cos[Pi/n], n, Method -> bertrand]

(*  True  *)
```

The `Automatic` method is unsuccessful:

```
SumConvergence[1 - Cos[Pi/n], n, Method -> Automatic]

(*  SumConvergence[1 - Cos[π/n], n, Method -> Automatic]  *)
```

Example: *Multiple tests*

Unfortunately, one cannot specify a list of methods for `SumConvergence[]` to try (even though `Automatic` tries many, many tests).

```
multitest // ClearAll;
multitest[tests_List][expr_, k_] :=
  Catch[
   With[{res = SumConvergence[expr, k, Method -> #]},
      If[FreeQ[res, SumConvergence], Throw@res]] & /@ tests;
   $Failed];

SumConvergence[1 - Cos[Pi/n], n, 
 Method -> "multitest[{Automatic, bertrand}]"]

(*  True  *)
```

One limitation on `multitest` is that the methods in `tests` are passed through `ToExpression`/`ToString` twice. Since these are not strictly inverse operations, some things are difficult to manage (see below).

Example: *Limit Comparison Test*

```
lct // ClearAll;
lct[expr2_][expr_, k_] :=
  Module[{res2, res1, res},
   res2 = SumConvergence[Abs@expr2, k];
   (res1 = Limit[Abs[expr/expr2], k -> Infinity];
     res = $Failed;
     If[res2 && TrueQ[0 <= res1 < Infinity],
      res = True,
      If[! res2 && TrueQ[0 < res1 <= Infinity],
       res = False]];
     res
     ) /; MatchQ[res2, True | False]
   ];

SumConvergence[1 - Cos[Pi/n], n, Method -> "lct[1/n^2]"]

(*  True  *)
```

*Limitations*

The following fails, because `ToExpression` is called twice:

```
SumConvergence[1 - Cos[Pi/n], n, 
 Method -> multitest[{"lct[1/n]", "lct[1/n^2]"}]]
```

Here's how the second `lct` gets clobbered:

```
ToExpression@ToString@ToExpression@"lct[1/n^2]"

(*  lct[n]  *)
```

By the way, `ToString[expr, InputForm]` is more reliable....

***Update:*** *Fix to the limitations*

Finally remembering the obvious, I checked the docs on `ToString`, and a workaround stared me in the face: There's an option one set to get `ToString` to use `InputForm`:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{ToString},
 SetOptions[ToString, FormatType -> InputForm];
 SumConvergence[1 - Cos[Pi/n], n, 
  Method -> multitest[{lct[1/n], lct[1/n^2]}]]]

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: I like: `lct /: Format[lct[x_], OutputForm] := InputForm[lct[x]]`

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks, I like that, too. I figured out `Format` affected `ToString` but didn't put it together with `InputForm` and `OutputForm`.